# Can i have more than one key for TouchId?

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic-view

I have an ionic app, and my user wants to login with using different users but with the same FaceId, for example. My question is, can i have more than one key for my app on IOS? What's the best way to implement this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [LocalAuthentication API](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/localauthentication/) just gives you a boolean `true`/`false` to the question "did the user successfully authenticate?". In fact, the iOS system only expects TouchID/FaceID to be used by one person. Thus, there's no way to have TouchID/FaceID tell you which user it authenticated, only that a user successfully authenticated. You'll have to implement some kind of choose-a-user flow yourself and then invoke `LocalAuthentication`